# all import file names become red in androidStudio

Tags: file, import

my PC shot down suddenly, when i start it again and start androidStudio all import files names became red. Projects still running. Should i reinstall Studio or any solution to come out from this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

the only solution of this problem is reinstall the studio and again download the sdk.